# System testing hangs inexplicably

Tags: 11.10, checkbox

I read that I can upload system testing reports to ubuntu site and was excited with it. But my last three efforts looks like gives me a hung 'system testing' process or it appears so for about an hour each. How I can find out what is happening and if it indeed hung?

https://launchpad.net/+login says I am already logged in, but I do not see any progress (or even unable to close the window as well) I am attaching the Screen shot as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine with 12.04. So looks like my system could not initiate the test from 11.10 somehow.

Answer (score 3):

The information will be submitted only if you have an launchpad account with the email id you provided.

Ubuntu [documentation and Video](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/participate/)